# android listview row takes up full height

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a relativelayout view for use with a listview. For some reason, even though I have set `layout_height` to `wrap_content`, the layout is taking up all the space it can. The result is that every row in the list is as tall as the screen!

I am not sure what is wrong with the view. It used to work just fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/cloudbkg" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/pay" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the getView function.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                try {
                    final JSONObject holder = getItem(position);
                    convertView = inflateView(R.layout.dumb);
                    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            try {
                                Intent i = new Intent(context, Pending.class);
                                i.putExtra("id", holder.getString("_id"));
                                context.startActivity(i);
                            } catch(Throwable e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){
                        public boolean onLongClick(View v){
                            try {
                                final CharSequence[] items = {"Pay", "Delete"};
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                                builder.setTitle(holder.getString("service"));
                                builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                                    }
                                }).create().show();
                            } catch(Throwable e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                    TextView t = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.amount);
                    t.setText(holder.getString("currency") + holder.getString("amount"));
                    setImg((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pic), holder.getJSONObject("to").getString("pic"));
                    t = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
                    t.setText(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(holder.getLong("time")*1000, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0, DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL));
                    t = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.service);
                    t.setText(holder.getString("service")); // url, co-ords, or shop

                } catch(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: What does your adapter's `getView` method look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the two images you use are not too large.

Comment: The only image in use is set to be 48dpx48dp

Comment: In your layout you're referencing two drawables: cloudbkg and pay

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the issue, but when you create a custom `ListActivity` layout, you need to set the list's screen layout as well as the layout of an individual row. Ensure that the resource file you pass to `setContentView()` contains a `ListView` object with the id `android:id/list` and that you are passing the row layout (as you posted above) to the appropriate adapter.

Comment: maybe [**this**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) will help

Comment: I think i made a minor mistake, I am not using listactivity but extending activity, and then setting up the listview myself.

Comment: ahh... that'll do it. `ListActivity` sets up the `ListView` for you by default, so you don't want to provide your own. If you want to customize it, make sure that you provide the `android:id="@android.id/list"` attribute (if you are using XML), or provide the `android.R.id.list` if you are customizing it in your code.

Comment: yeah but the problem i am facing is with the row being full height, instead of wrap_content

Comment: even after you fixed the class so that it extends `ListActivity`? Hmm, ok... well then maybe it has to do with the adapter. Can you provide more code and information about how you are binding data to your rows? Are you querying a database and using a `CursorLoader`? is your data fixed and you are using an `ArrayAdapter`? I ask because the default implementation of `getView` (as well as a number of other methods common to all adapters) depends on the class, so I can't know for sure if you are implementing the correct adapter methods.

Comment: no i meant i cant extend listactivity, i have to extend mapactivity for use in the app.

Comment: oh... well you didn't mention that. can you clarify _exactly_ how you are approaching writing your application? you really haven't provided enough information for others to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how tall the row would take approximately(eg: 60dp), then instead of giving `wrap_content` give `layout_height="60dp"` in the root RelativeLayout. You can then use `layout_centerVertical` to correctly align the views.

If that is not acceptable try giving different background colors to different views as a way to debug and see which view is responsible for taking all the space.

Comment: As soon as I create a new xml with linear or relatively layout, it becomes full height

Comment: did you try hardcoding a height value?

Comment: that seems to fix, but is not a prefered solution. I am trying to see what has changed.

Comment: you can also remove some viewGroups, and see which one is causing the problem. Start with a very minimal row, make sure it works, and then build upon it